# Python experience and level points for a simple game

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am developing a simple game.  I want there to be 100 experience points before an increase in level, and the points reset.  Example, a person gets 12 points(there current is 99), it should go to level 2 and 11 exp points.  It should also account for if they get 244 points, then 2 levels and 44 points should be given respectively. My current code

```
points = points_sale
def bonus(price):
    if 0 == int(price):
        bonus = 0
        return bonus
    if 1 <= int(price) <= 100:
        bonus = 1
        return bonus
    if 101 <= int(price) <= 250:
        bonus = 2
        return bonus
    if 251 <= int(price) <= 500:
        bonus = 5
        return bonus
    if 501 <= int(price) <= 1000:
        bonus = 10
        return bonus
    if 1001 <= int(price) <= 5000:
        bonus = 25
        return bonus
    if 5001 <= int(price):
        bonus = 50
        return bonus
adjusted = bonus(price=price)
newpoints = int((currentPoints + points + adjusted)*quantity)
if newpoints > 100:
<insert code here>
```

How do i get the experience points to reset if they are above 100 and add a +1 to level.

Comment: So, what's your question? Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: Use `%` the modulus operator, e.g. `newpoints = newpoints % 100` or shorthand `newpoints %= 100`. You can also get the level use integer division, e.g. `levels = newpoints // 100` (before the above operation). This is very common in `python` that there is function to combine this: `levels, newpoints = divmod(newpoints, 100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can can use `divmod` to divide and get the remainder at the same time:

```
newpoints = 244

levels_up, exp_leftover = divmod(newpoints, 100)

print(levels_up, exp_leftover) # >> (2, 44)
```